# How to run two loop simultaneously in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to simulate the movement of vehicles in MATLAB. The output will be in plot. For movement, I am using hgtransform function.  I need to run these for loops simultaneously. Kindly suggest me a way. 
I am even open for any other method, from which the movement of two points in the can be shown simultaneously. I need the movement of points in a single plain.

```
for t=linspace(0,1,100)
    g.Matrix = makehgtform('translate',ptg2 + t*(ptg3-ptg2));
    drawnow;
    waitfor(r);
end

time = r.TotalElapsedTime;
fprintf('Iteration: %f - Time Elapsed: %f\n',i,time)
r = rateControl(21);

for t=linspace(0,1,100)
    g.Matrix = makehgtform('translate',ptg3 + t*(ptg4-ptg3));
    drawnow;
    waitfor(r);
end

time = r.TotalElapsedTime;
fprintf('Iteration: %f - Time Elapsed: %f\n',i,time)
```

Comment: Why not run loop1, loop2 and only update the figure once you have the two values?

Comment: Since I am using it for simulation, I need the intermediate loop values also.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a [timer](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/use-a-matlab-timer-object.html) for each action.

Alternatively, just have one for loop with all timesteps, and an if statement for each action, which determines whether the action should be run that timestep.